# Springboot Websocket Client to read messages from a Websocket stream with different port

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I am new to both springboot and websockets so please be gentle and this is my last question chance on this account. I have a websocket jar that sends messages from two urls `ws:localhost/operations` and `ws:localhost/prices` from `8080` port. My task is to read those messages. The Jar file streams messages like:

For operation:

> "data":{ "description":"lorem ipsum", "id":"OJ1136453723" },
> "type":"DELETE"

For price:

> "data":{ "price":1384.1685, "id":"WN6427148286" }, "type":"PRICE"

I have **spring-boot-starter-websocket, spring-boot-starter-security** and **lombok** as dependencies.

I seem to be connecting to the jar file, because powershell says "**Socket connected
Frame TEXT (fin=true, buffer len = 48)**" when I run my code but it only hits the Application breakpoints whenever I debug, it **doesnt even go to controller or config classes**. It may be an obvious mistake but I am a bit lost so any help would be appriciated. Also, my port for this client is 8443 which is specified in application.yml and it starts there.

**My Client:**

```
public class WSClient{

    private static String URL = "ws://localhost:8080";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        WebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient();
        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(client);
        stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
        StompSessionHandler sessionHandler = new MyStompSessionHandler();
        stompClient.connect(URL, sessionHandler);

        new Scanner(System.in).nextLine(); 
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class MsgController {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

    @MessageMapping("/operations")
    public Operations operations(Operations operations)throws Exception{
        System.out.println(operations);
        simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/operations", operations);
        return operations;
    }
```

**StompSessionHandler:**

```
public class MyStompSessionHandler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter {

    private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyStompSessionHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void afterConnected(StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
        logger.info("New session established : " + session.getSessionId());
        session.subscribe("/operations", this);
        System.out.println("Subscribed to /operations");
        logger.info("Subscribed to /operations");
    }

    @Override
    public void handleException(StompSession session, StompCommand command, StompHeaders headers, byte[] payload, Throwable exception) {
        logger.error("Got an exception", exception);
    }

    @Override
    public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
        return Operations.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
        Operations ops = (Operations) payload;
        System.out.println(ops);
    }
}
```

**Operations:**

```
@lombok.Data
public class Operations{
    public String description;
    public String id;
    public String type;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Thanks to help of @OkanKonur the problem is that StompHandler's afterConnected is not called even though it seems like they are connected. We tried it with the github link he's given in the comments and it seems to work. The jar file is most probably not a spring project so is there a way to solve this? It still can't read anything.

Comment: You try to subscribe to `/operations` endpoint but your base ws URL also has this. Maybe try to create the base URL with `URI.create("ws://localhost:8080")`

Comment: @OkanKonur yeah that was a huge mistake lol, I fixed it but still not going into controller or stompsessionhandler. I am not sure if I need to trigger them or springboot does it itself. I am also editing the questions according to your comment thanks a lot!

Comment: You can move your stompClient initalization in your main method to a @bean class elsewhere and inject it in a new controller in your web app, which will trigger the client. Your current version runs the spring application after your initalization. Or, you can look into this repo: https://github.com/nielsutrecht/spring-boot-websocket-client

Comment: @OkanKonur changed the question according to your comment thanks a lot!